# Updating field inside a repository

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm creating a CRON in my Symfony 4 App (command) to archive news that is older than 60 days. How should this be done?

My first instinct was to add a method to my `NewsRepository` to retrieve all news that needs to be archive and update their `isArchived` boolean method from false to true if it's the case.

Then, I had this idea of adding the logic for archiving the news inside the repository so that it's usable outside the Command. I could also put the logic (MySQL Updates) inside the Command and just have the ''find'' query inside the repository.

Which of these approaches is preferable, and why? Should my repository method be `findNewsToArchive` and do the update logic inside the command, or should it be `archiveAllNewsThatNeedsToBeArchived` and do all the logic in the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using all your logic in your command is a bad practice for your case you have technically two separate things find/archive, if I were you I'll use my repository with two function `findNews(array $criteria): array`, `archive(array $news): void`

One will find the news based on your criteria (60 days ...) the other function will archive them. And you can reused them as much as you like and it's easy to maintain. Your command will only use these two function to find and archive based on your criteria

Comment: So you suggest I should split it in two methods but use them in my repository am I correct?

Comment: Exaclty ! so you can reuse each block

Comment: But doing update task inside a repository is good practice? I'm a little confused because in the past I've mostly been using Repository to do ''FIND'' queries, I tought that doing update or such things was bad practice but now that I think about it those are actions that I do over the whole repository it could make sense

Comment: A repository is not specific for "finding" you can do everything db related to your entity and each one of those method should only do one and only one thing so you can reuse them.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is update the `isArchived`-flag you do not need to fetch any entities. Instead you can directly issue an [UPDATE-query](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#update-queries), e.g. something like this:

```php
class NewsRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    // ...

    public function archiveOldNews(\DateTimeImmutable $olderThan): void
    {
        $dql = 'UPDATE App\Entity\News news SET news.isArchived = true WHERE news.createdOn < :older';

        $updateQuery = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
        $updateQuery->setParameter('older', $olderThan);
        $updateQuery->execute();
    }
}
```

This will update all entries directly in the database making the operation both atomic and fast. In some cases this might prevent issues with data being changed between fetching, changing everything in PHP and then submitting the data back to the database.